# Custom BotState storage - deleting old state data entries

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I have successfully implemented custom bot state service to store state data into my Azure Cosmos DB using [following article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-cosmosdb). What I however noticed is, that the state data collection can grow relatively large especially in number of records.

I would like to implement a scheduled task which will delete all state data entries related to `ConversationData` and `PrivateConversationData` older than a day (for example) while keeping the `UserData` untouched. To compare the timestamps I was thinking about using the Cosmos DB system property `_ts`.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a existing out-of-the-box solution? I was thinking about adapting the `/deleteProfile` command, however according to [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/497252e8d9949be20baa2cebaa6ce56de04461cf/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/DeleteProfileScorable.cs#L90) it seems to be using the `Clear()` calls which do not physically remove the database entries.
2. Is there a simple way how to distinguish between individual types of state data? Looks like regular expressions is the only option.
3. Would there be any consequences apart from losing the state data?

Comment: There is a `DeleteBeforeAsync` method for TableLogger but not for TableBotData (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/TableLogger.cs#L258)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a existing out-of-the-box solution?

At the moment, In Bot SDK I do not find any method/function that could be used to delete state data older than specified a datetime from cosmos db.

> Is there a simple way how to distinguish between individual types of state data?

If you check the data (document) stored in your cosmos db, you will find that the id of document is saved with specific pattern, such as: the documents of **ConversationData** with id `<channel>:conversation<conversation ID>` and the documents of **PrivateConversationData** with id `<channel>:private<conversation ID>:<user ID>`. As you mentioned, you can use regular expression to match and detect the type of state data.

*You can refer this regular expression and below sample code to delete your old documents.*

```
string pattern = @"(:conversation)|(:private)";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rgx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);
```

***Sample code:***

```
string EndpointUrl = "https://xxxx.documents.azure.com:443/";
string PrimaryKey = "{your_key}";
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), PrimaryKey);

FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 };

DateTime dtn = new DateTime(2018, 1, 25);

IQueryable<Document> DocQueryInSql = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(
        UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName),
        "SELECT * FROM c WHERE udf.ToDate(c._ts) < '"+ dtn.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'",
        queryOptions);

string pattern = @"(:conversation)|(:private)";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rgx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);

foreach (Document doc in DocQueryInSql)
{
    if (rgx.Matches(doc.Id).Count>0)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("\tRead {0}", doc.Id);

        await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("{your_db_name}", "{your_collection_name", doc.Id));
    }
}
```

*My [User-defined functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#udf) (ToDate):*

```
function epochToDate (ts) { 
   return new Date(ts * 1000);
}
```

> Would there be any consequences apart from losing the state data?

It depends on what you want to use these state data, if you retrieve the state data but it has been deleted, which might cause exceptions or some functionalities you achieved not working.

***Note:***

- To run a scheduled task, you can try Azure WebJobs or Functions
- For more detailed information about operating cosmos db, please check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started#DeleteDocument)